# No edit, copy and delete option in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have inserted some values into two columns but i can't find the Edit, Copy, Delete options in the browsing page in phpmyadmin.

I thought that i need to update phpmyadmin but i still have the same problem after updating.

```
CREATE TABLE school_s(
students varchar(255),
id int 
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a field primary key in your table to see those options.
like-

```
CREATE TABLE school_s(
students varchar(255),
id int(10) PRIMARY KEY
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table should contain a primary key which can uniquely identify each row.Only then you would able to see those options

```
CREATE TABLE school_s(
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
`students` varchar(255),
`description` varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```